# Guidance for creating client package for my api/webapi

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I've tried, but I couldn't find any info about it.

Let's say that I have some webapis for my company that other devs (or qa) are going to use in theirs applications, and for easier use of my apis I'd like to create a library with client so that I can control how other devs are communicating with my api. So basically they can just install this package, add webapi url to configuration, inject necessary dependencies and use it. Is there any pattern, guidance etc. for creating such packages with client? I'm not talking about good practices how to create web api, rest api etc, but just this specific client package.

I've tried googling some tips or guidance about this (or maybe just generic instructions), but all I could find is how to create REST API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSwag. With NSwag you can:

- Generate Open API/Swagger specification from your Web API controllers. It is just a JSON document describing you API
- Include an Html/JavaScript front end in your Web API application where users can see your API and invoke it.
- Generate C# clients to invoke your web API.

Useful links:

- https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio